# Create submenu under linkbar option in flex

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

Is it possible in flex to create submenu under linkbar option? if yes, then please show me the solution.

Answer (score 1):

would a menubar make more sense in this situation? You can do this, but you would have to extend the linkbar yourself and add the functionality to it.  Its not just a few trivial lines.